# Look for an attribute in an eager loded subsection of a subsection, without causing a SQL call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select-n-plus-1

I have a set of models like below (the actual setup displayed here is a simplified mockup):

```
Blog 
has_many :posts

Post
has_many :comments
# contributor_id is a part of Post

Contributor
# having fields such as :id, :name, etc.
```

I iterate through them like this:

```
Blog.all.includes(:posts => :contributors).each do |blog|
render partial: 'blog_item', :locals => { :blog => blog } 
end
```

Inside '`blog_item`' partial view I would like to determine whether a **specific** Contributor (id: 123, name:"john") is included among the `posts`. As a general problem it is quite easy, but I want to do this **without having an SQL call** (causing N+1).

Currently, I am solving this like so:

```
blog.posts.pluck(:contributor_id).include?(123)
```

which causes an SQL call (and subsequently an N+1).

I can't do something like this:

```
blog.posts.include?(:contributor_id)
```

So, how can this be solved without having that extra SQL call?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to solve this for quite some time. Posted the question, read a subsection of an article directly after and solved it in 2 mins.

```
@contributor = Contributor.find(123)
Blog.all.includes(:posts => :contributors).each do |blog|
  render partial: 'blog_item', :locals => { :blog => blog } 
end

# Inside blog_item
blog.posts.map(&:contributor).include?(@contributor)
```